# Relative succinctness of NFAs and regular expressions

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

What is known about the succintness of NFAs, relative to regular expressions?

In order to clarify the question, let me explain what I know. The regular languages can be characterized by any of the following:

1. A language is regular iff it can be recognized by an NFA.
2. A language is regular iff it can be recognized by a DFA.
3. A language is regular iff it can be defined by an MSO formula.
4. A language is regular iff it can be described by a regular expression.

The family of languages $(\{w\in\{0,1\}^* \mid |w|>n, w_{|w|-1-n}=0\})_{n\in\omega}$ has NFAs with $n+1$ states. For DFAs, there is a lower bound of $2^n$ states. This family exemplifies that the translation from NFAs to DFAs necessarily incurs a worst-case exponential explosion of size.

In the other direction, there is no explosion, because each DFA is an NFA. Together, we can say that NFAs are *exponentially more succinct* than DFAs.

A similar result holds for the comparison of automata (either NFAs or DFAs) to MSO formulae: The formulae are non-elementarily more succinct.

I am aware that the translation from regular expressions to NFAs is linear and that there is an exponential translation in the other direction. Now to the actual question: Is it known that an exponential blowup cannot be avoided? What NFAs (or even DFAs) witness this? What techniques are used to prove non-existence of short regular expressions?

[This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89626/regex-for-divisibility-by-123-in-binary-strings) leads me to assume that divisibility languages are witnesses. That was what prompted the present question.

Comment: See Theorem 24 in the survey [From Finite Automata to Regular Expressions and Back—A Summary on Descriptional Complexity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5594.pdf) by Gruber and Holzer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DFAs can be exponentially more succinct than regular expressions. A simple example is the language of all words over $\{a,b\}$ in which the number of $a$s and the number of $b$s are each divisible by $n$. This is accepted by a DFA of size $n^2$, but requires a regular expression of length $2^{\Omega(n)}$. For proof, see Example 23 in the survey [From finite automata to regular expressions and back](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5594.pdf) by Gruber and Holzer.

Gruber and Holzer improved this in their paper [Tight bounds on the descriptional complexity of regular expressions](http://geb.uni-giessen.de/geb/volltexte/2012/9080/pdf/Ifig_report0901.pdf), also mentioned in their survey (Theorem 24 of the survey). In fact, they prove an even stronger result (Theorem 8 of the paper): there is a language described by a regular expression of length $O(n)$ whose complement requires a regular expression of length $2^{2^{\Omega(n)}}$. (A regular expression of length $O(n)$ corresponds to an NFA having $O(n)$ states and so to a DFA having $2^{O(n)}$ states, whose complement has the same number of states.) The regular expression with this wondrous properties, over the alphabet $\{0,1,\$\}$, is
$$
(0+1)^{\geq 1} + (\epsilon + \Sigma^*\$)\bigl((0+1)^{\leq 4n-1}\$ + (0+1)^{\geq 4n+1}\bigr)\Sigma^* \\
+ \Sigma^*\$(0+1)^{3n}(0+1)^*0\Sigma^{n+1}1\Sigma^* \\
+ \Sigma^*\$(0+1)^{3n}(0+1)^*1\Sigma^{n+1}0\Sigma^* \\
+ \Sigma^*\$(0+1)^*0\Sigma^{2n}1\Sigma^* \\
+ \Sigma^*\$(0+1)^*1\Sigma^{2n}0\Sigma^*
$$
We can even obtain an example over the binary alphabet $\{a,b\}$ using the homomorphism
$$
0 \mapsto abbb, \quad 1 \mapsto aabb, \quad \$ \mapsto aaab.
$$

The way all of these results are proved is via the concept of [star height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height): a language of star height $h$ requires a regular expression of length $2^{\Omega(h)}$. Unfortunately lower bounds on the star height are rather difficult to establish, so instead one uses the more manageable [cycle rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_rank), a theorem of McNaughton identifying the two for a class of languages known as *bideterministic*. (For more details, consult either of the sources cited above.)